# Is there a way to disable item name changing from anvils in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In a server the anvils are disabled from being used for glitches to get money using anvil item name changing.

Is there a way to disable item name changing from anvils in minecraft?
(Thus keeping the anvils working, but preventing the glitch)

Comment: As a workaround you might simply disallow anvils to be placed to begin with

Comment: I think he's trying to have anvils available for use, without the bug though.

Answer (score 3):

If you're running a Bukkit server, you could install the [AnvilGlitchPatch](https://web.archive.org/web/20130515120434/https://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/anvilglitchpatch) plugin, but the original Bukkit page link is broken and the JAR is not available to download from archive.org.

> This is a basic fix for the infinite money glitch with renaming items. This plugin will fix the glitch where you can make infinite money from renaming an item on an anvil.

Comment: Link to patch is dead.

Comment: @ppperry Thanks, unfortunately I can't find a replacement and the original plugin isn't available to download on archive.org